# How to use "with" in sql?

Tags: sql

I am having a problem with this, i have this code

```
with 
    a as(select * from CASH_DENOM where Curr_SourceId=1 and convert(date,Curr_EntryDate)='2015-1-28'),
    b as (select * from CASH_DENOM where Curr_SourceId=2 and convert(date,Curr_EntryDate)='2015-1-28')
select * from a, b where a.Curr_EntryDate=b.Curr_EntryDate
```

table a has a result of of 7 rows and table b has also 7 rows but when i run this code it returns me 49 rows why is it like that? it is supposed to be only 14 rows..

**EDITS/UPDATE:**

```
with 
    a as(select Curr_EntryDate date1, Curr_Denom denom, Curr_Pieces pcs, Curr_Total ctotal from CASH_DENOM where Curr_SourceId=1 and convert(date,Curr_EntryDate)='2015-1-28'),
    b as (select Curr_EntryDate date2, Curr_Denom denom1, Curr_Pieces pcs1, Curr_Total ctotal1 from CASH_DENOM where Curr_SourceId=2 and convert(date,Curr_EntryDate)='2015-1-28')

select a.denom,a.pcs,a.ctotal,b.denom1,b.pcs1,b.ctotal1 from a inner join b on a.date1=b.date2;
```

by the way i am doing `inner join` because i want to have 6 columns `(denom, pcs,ctotal,denom1, pcs1,ctotal1)` and 14 rows. is this possible?.

Using union gives me only 4 columns `(date2, denom1, pcs1, ctotal1)` and 14 rows

**UPDATE II**

The output should be like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 denom  | pcs | ctotal | denom1 | pcs1 | ctotal1 |
-------------------------------------------------------
 100.00 | 2   | 200.00 | 100.00 | 5    | 500.00  |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

[heres the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRwgk.png)

Something like that..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You're doing a join, not a union.

Comment: i also use `inner join` and that has the same result

Comment: `select * from a inner join b on a.Curr_EntryDate=b.Curr_EntryDate;` that is also giving me same result

Comment: This is going to sound harsher than intended, but you really need to look at some tutorials/guides for SQL to learn the fundamentals and then revisit your problem afterwards.

Comment: wow this one works fine `select * from a
union all
select * from b`

Comment: I told you to do a union...

Comment: @jarlh he doesn't even need a union.. just to change the where clause to in(1,2)

Comment: I still think 7 + 7 = 14 indicates that a union, or rather a union all, is what OP wants.

Comment: Yes because I can guess he is new to sql, so he is not familiar with IN() and uses two selects instead of one..

Comment: Could be... Seems like OP should practice the basics before moving on to WITH and other complex stuff.

Comment: what i want to do is to add columns and rows and not only the rows i have updated my question..

Comment: Why is this flagged VB .NET?

Comment: i will run this code thru vb.net

Comment: That does not change the fact that this question has nothing to do with VB but only with SQL. I also have an Android phone but do not include Android in all my questions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, its either you want to join those results together, and then you should have **7** results and not 14, or in your case 49 because your join condition equals to 1=1(you are comparing date fields that are always 28/1/15 on all of them) so each row is beeing attached to each row. In that case you should change your join condition from

```
where a.Curr_EntryDate=b.Curr_EntryDate --(Equals to 1=1)
```

to something like:

```
where a.ID_FIELD=b.ID_FIELD --(fields that have the same value that you want to combine their results)
```

Or, what you want is just to unite those two results, and in that case you are looking for a union and you need this:

```
with 
    a as(select * from CASH_DENOM where Curr_SourceId=1 and convert(date,Curr_EntryDate)='2015-1-28'),
    b as (select * from CASH_DENOM where Curr_SourceId=2 and convert(date,Curr_EntryDate)='2015-1-28')
select * from a
union all
select * from b
```

And lastly, you don't even need two selects / union / join / with or anything, this can be done with one select and IN statement like this:

```
select * from CASH_DENOM
where Curr_SourceId in (1,2)
and convert(date,Curr_EntryDate)='2015-1-28'
```

Comment: sir @sagi, this one is nice but i have updated my question

Comment: if the result of this is what i want then i will only use `where Curr_SourceId=1 and Curr_SourceId=2` thats because i am not yet familiar yet in `IN` i have updated the question..

Comment: Its ok, but again, I didn't understand what you want to achieve, update your question and give us input and desired output, that way I'll be able to understand @prettyme

Comment: i have updated the question hope you understand the output i want @sagi

Comment: @prettyme thats not enough, i asked for input as well so i can understand the logic you want to make, join based on what? and ETC.. and I'm still waiting for the V

Comment: in vb.net i have datetimepicker, datagridview and button when clicking button it will run the code base on selected date  and its result will be transfer to datagridview.. sorry it is so complicate for you. I just want to show the cash break down (cash from vault and from cashbox, that is why i have 2 `Curr_SourceId`1 and 2)

Comment: I understand, and it won't be that complicated if you will post an example of input in table a and table b and then desired output from it

Comment: have you seen the image? @sagi

Answer (score -1):

You need a union. You are doing a join. Think about the condition "where a.Curr_EntryDate=b.Curr_EntryDate"

7 rows from a have that value and 7 rows from b have that value, making 7*7 = 49 rows

Try

```
Select a union all select b
```